# Blogger blog without the Blogspot branding

Tags: blogger

I have seen a few standard Blogspot URLs, like `mysite.blogspot.com`, where the standard Blogspot branding is not visible, like the header on top " More  Next Blog» , etc"

How does one create that? It appears like a paid Blogspot URL, but don't think they were paid.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Blogger Navbar]

It is called Navbar in Blogger

To switch it off , go to Layout Tab in the Blogger Dashboard , there click the Edit button of the **Navbar** widget (It normally present in the Upper right corner) and select the Off option (See Screenshot below) and Save

[image]